# Transformar columna de DataFrame en serie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con un DataFrame y necesito usar una columna 'nombre' del DataFrame como indice, el campo 'Descripcion' como las columnas y 'precioUnidad' como los valores de las filas.

Describo los campos disponibles:

```
Index(['Nombre', '', 'Descripcion', 'PrecioUnidad'], dtype='object')

                     Nombre  ... PrecioUnidad
75    HIPERDINO LAS ROTONDAS  ...         1.49
76    HIPERDINO LAS ROTONDAS  ...         0.91
77    HIPERDINO LAS ROTONDAS  ...         0.00
78    HIPERDINO LAS ROTONDAS  ...         1.35
79    HIPERDINO LAS ROTONDAS  ...         1.45
...                      ...  ...          ...
2631   HIPERTREBOL Hoya Fria  ...         1.39
2632   HIPERTREBOL Hoya Fria  ...         1.59
2633   HIPERTREBOL Hoya Fria  ...         2.39
2634   HIPERTREBOL Hoya Fria  ...         0.00
2635   HIPERTREBOL Hoya Fria  ...         0.00

[1635 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

```
                    Descripcion 1 -          Descripcion 2    -    Descripcion 3
Nombre 1             PrecioUnidad            PrecioUnidad          PrecioUnidad
Nombre 2             PrecioUnidad            PrecioUnidad          PrecioUnidad
Nombre 3             PrecioUnidad            PrecioUnidad          PrecioUnidad
Nombre 4             PrecioUnidad            PrecioUnidad          PrecioUnidad
```

He probado a usar `transform()` pero no consigo que los datos, se muestren de esa manera. Alguna alma caritativa me puede orientar. ¿Quizás alguna función de DataFrame o tengo que currarlo a mano?.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Hola Moises, si lo que quieres es convertir los valores de una de las columnas (Descripcion) en columnas dejando el precio como valores, `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` debería solventar el problema. No obstante, tengo algunas dudas, como ¿que es y que debe pasar con la columna sin nombre que parece que tienes? ¿Una misma descripcion es compartida por varios nombres? ¿Pueden aparecer mas de una fila con el mismo nombre y descripcion?. Seria de gran ayuda que agregaras un ejemplo minimo de tu Dataframe de partida (algunas filas solo, pero que muestren el problema)  y su salida esperada.

Comment: Buen día,
Gracias por la rápida respuesta a ambos, FJSevilla con pandas.DataFrame.pivot he conseguido lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias

                                               IdEmpresa  ...         PrecioUnidad
Nombre                              CARREFOUR LA BALLENA   ... CARREFOUR LAS ARENAS
Descripcion                                                ...                     
Ambrosia avella 14pz. C12                              18  ...                  0.0
Ambrosia blanca 14pz. C12                              18  ...                  0.0